# Plotting single row of matrix

Tags: r, matrix, plot, graph, row

Hi I have a matrix that has multiple rows, i can plot the entire matrix with `plot(range01(matrix_name),type = "l")` but when I  do `plot(range01(matrix_name[1,]),type = "l")` like this its giving me error saying that

```
  formal argument "type" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

How can I plot with a single row only?

`range01` is function that is converting values between 0 and 1.

Matrix :

```
     V1         V2      V3        V4        V5        V6
1 0.1302677 0.1338888 0.1375044 0.1411146 0.1447193 0.1483186 
2 0.9863382 0.9848000 0.9832758 0.9817656 0.9802694 0.9787871
```

Comment: Maybe use `dput` to include the matrix? 
Also what about this? `plot(range01(matrix_name[1,, drop = FALSE]),type = "l")`

Comment: You are missing a closed square bracket in: `plot(range01(matrix_name[1,),type = "l")` after `matrix_name[1,)`.

Comment: SamR Sorry its typo error in post , but I tried with matrix_name[1,])  and its giving me the error.

Comment: What is `range01(..)`?